# Upgrade to JDK 10 and encountered extensive compile errors in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, java-10, java-11

UPDATE: I eventually discovered that the trouble described below was just the initial presenting problem. The actual issue is that after updating from Java 8 to Java 10 (and 11) Eclipse was unable to compile my project properly. The JDK library and other settings were configured properly, and I was getting nearly 1,000 compile errors.

**There is no reason to read any further**

I upgraded a swing app from JDK 8 to JDK 10 (Oracle Java on a Mac), and eclipse complains that `javax.accessibility.Accessible` is missing, and required by one of my classes. I understand what that error means, but I can't figure out why eclipse can't find that package. I've searched the net for over an hour, and I can't a hint of anyone having this problem. It seems I should just be able to access that package from within the JDK, but I'm obviously missing something.

EDIT2:

I turned off the flag to abort the build when it has an error, and I see now there are hundreds of errors. It's hard to say which ones are primary, but a common occurrence is `class java.awt.<SomeClass> is not accessible`. This seems to occur for every awt class. My code is not organized as modules, and I see `java.desktop` as implicitly available on the `Modulepath`. Also, the ant build of this code works fine.

EDIT:

As suggested in the comments, this is likely an IDE misconfiguration, but I don't know what I can fix. I've been away from Java for a few years, and while I've kept up enough to know that the JDK was re-organized with JDK 9, and modules were introduced, I don't know if there's something I'm supposed to do explicitly to make the `javax.accessibility` package available on the classpath. I just added a JRE System library to the build path in the project the way I've always done with Java projects in Eclipse.

In the build path config UI, I see the JRE System Library (bound to JDK 10) as the only entry under `Modulepath`. Under the JRE System Library, I see a number of modules, and above them is an entry `Is Module` which I can edit. It shows me available modules on the left, and explicitly and implicitly included modules in two tree tables on the right. None of these include `javax.accessibility`, but `jdk.accessibility` is listed as explicitly included. None of the available modules on the left seem to have any relationship to accessibility. So I'm at a loss as to what I can do further to include that missing package. Some swing classes are depending on it, so it seems it should just be there by default.

Comment: Maybe something you need has been removed?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/deprecated-list.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/deprecated-list.html

Comment: The javax.accessibility package has not been removed. This sounds like a setup issue in the IDE. Alternatively, maybe you have migrated your code to a module and are missing`requires java.desktop`.?

Comment: I agree it's likely an IDE problem. The missing package is required by JMenu (and probably other Swing classes), so it should be available without any extraordinary measures. And it's the entire package that's missing, not just a class or two. Please see my edit to the OP. I'm new to Java modules. I didn't do anything explicit to migrate my code to a module structure. Am I supposed to do something to explicitly include this module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Eclipse does not support Java 10+ except in specific (older) releases. I had been using the latest release (4.9.0), and that was presenting extensive compilation problems (nearly 1,000 errors) using Java 10 and Java 11 JDKs. (The `javax.accessibility` issue described in my question was only the first presenting system.)

I installed Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) and all the compilation problems using JDKs 10 and 11 disappeared. There was an issue at first, which was easily solved. After importing an existing Java project into the workspace, there were even more compile errors than before. This was because the JRE System Library setting in the .project file was apparently incompatible. The JRE appeared as an unbound library under `Classpath`. I just removed that and added the JRE System Library under `Modulepath`, and everything compiled with no errors.

I saw a post from several months ago that Eclipse Photon support for Java 10 was in the works, but I didn't try it.

Comment: Eclipse has supported Java 10 for a few months now , there is no point reverting to an old alpha version. Both Eclipse 4.8.0 and 4.9.0 support Java 10 out of the box, never had any issues with them. Eclipse 4.9.0 supports Java 11 with this additional patch: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-11-support-eclipse-2018-09-49

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad to know there is a patch for 4.9.0 to support JDK 11. I'll try the patch out, but I'm certain that 4.9.0 did not work for me with JDK 10 or 11. I spent the better part of two days trying to make it work with either of those. When I switched to Oxygen, it worked immediately. My 4.9.0 workspace still fails with JDK 10 and 11, but it works with JDK 8 and 9 (the latter is EOL, but I tested it anyway). I hope I can get 4.9.0 to work with JDK 10. I'm not using JDK 11 because it's missing the ant tasks (ant-javafx.jar). I could copy it from JDK 10, but maybe it's not supported.

Comment: The Eclipse 4.9.0 I tried was obtained through the Eclipse Installer. I also tried downloading that version directly. Both versions behaved as described above. This was the Java Developers Eclipse package.